# Differentiating single/multiple selection in polls in a mobile app

Tags: checkboxes, radio-buttons, poll

as the title stated, I would like to seek some ideas on the need of actually differentiating the choices. see below:

- A: traditional checkboxes for multi-selects, radio button for single
  select
- B: uses only checkboxes, perhaps with visual cues to
  inform user (see select state below)

[image: default state]

[image: selected state]

Comment: Checkboxes and radio buttons are proven concepts. Why would you break these concepts and try to fix them again with a non-proven concept? It only adds extra complexity for users, designers (otherwise you wouldn't have to ask this question) and developers.

Answer (score 1):

From your question, I cannot understand why your seek some ideas - do you have any indication that the established way of distinguishing single/multiple selection using checkbox/radiobutton does not work with your users, or for your use case?

In the absence of a (very) good reason to deviate from established practice, I'd always return to that established practice. A very good rationale is given in [Jakob's Law in Internet Use](https://www.nngroup.com/videos/jakobs-law-internet-ux/).

Answer (score 0):

Radio buttons are widely used and well understood, even on mobile design systems:

- https://m3.material.io/components/radio-button/overview
- https://developer.apple.com/design/human-interface-guidelines/toggles#Radio-buttons

Using your alternative seems strictly worse: If I accidentally select option A and want to switch option B, I first have to understand I can't click B (it's greyed out), but have to uncheck A instead (which, given that everything else is greyed out, isn't entirely clear whether that's even possible), and only then can check B.

In stark contrast to this, with a radio button the user can just click option B and be done with it.